# Analyze an entire sheet and display the results in a table

Tags: r

How can I analyze a complete excel sheet and show the result in a table, classify them by area and by average population and on a map using R, in addition to creating a visualization, the population of a country is analyzed.
compare columns and totals

Comment: Welcome to SO Rossy. Please review [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. While the SO community are very helpful, you will increase your chances of getting an answer if your make your question easier to answer. Thanks